# What is the [PATTERN] parameter for "systemctl list-units"

Tags: systemd, systemctl, documentation

The [man page for systemctl](http://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemctl.html) says:

> #### Unit Commands
>
> **`list-units [PATTERN...]`**
>
>   List known units (subject to limitations specified with
>   `-t`
>   ). 
>   If one or more
>   *`PATTERN`*
>   s are specified,
>   only units matching one of them are shown.
>
> This is the default command.

My question is, what does it mean by `[PATTERN]`?

When I execute `systemctl list-units`,
I get a relatively long list of the loaded units. 
But if I add a third argument,
I get an error message `Too many arguments.` 
So I am curious as to what parameters are valid
for the `[PATTERN]` argument listed in the man page.

(I'm running Arch Linux and have version 227 of systemd.)

Comment: Note, for reference, that, when the question was asked, the man page looked like [this](https://web.archive.org/web/20151113090941/http://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemctl.html#Unit%20Commands).

Comment: (1) I can't tell from your post how much or how little you know.  So, since you show no sign of knowing this, and it is responsive to your question, (1a) when a man page says something in square brackets, like ``[NAME]``, it usually means that the thing is optional: you can specify one, or not.  And (1b) when the page adds "`...`" (e.g., ``[NAME...]``), that means that you can specify any number of the thing: one ***or more*** or none. … (Cont’d)

Comment: (Cont’d) …  (2) Your question is unclear.  You have a command with one argument, and you say you “add[ed] a third argument”.  What was the *second* argument? (And I hope you tried more than one experiment before you posted your question. We prefer questions that show some effort by the asker to find the answer themselves.)

Answer (score 15):

From the same page:

> #### Parameter Syntax
>
> Unit commands listed above take either a single unit name (designated
>   as NAME), or multiple unit specifications (designated as PATTERN...).
>   In the first case, [...]
>
> In the second case, shell-style globs will be matched against
>   currently loaded units; literal unit names, with or without a suffix,
>   will be treated as in the first case. This means that literal unit
>   names always refer to exactly one unit, but globs may match zero units
>   and this is not considered an error.
>
> Glob patterns use [fnmatch(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/fnmatch.3.html), so normal shell-style globbing
>   rules are used, and "`*`", "`?`", "`[]`" may be used. See [glob(7)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/glob.7.html)
>   for more details. The patterns are matched against the names of
>   currently loaded units, and patterns which do not match anything are
>   silently skipped. For example:
>
> ```
> # systemctl stop sshd@*.service
> ```
>
> will stop all `sshd@.service` instances.

Comment: What result do you see if you type `systemctl list-units sshd@*.service`?  I get `Too many arguments.`.  Maybe a bug in my version of systemctl?

Comment: @GabrielSouthern [it's a bug](https://www.mail-archive.com/systemd-devel@lists.freedesktop.org/msg34238.html). :D

Comment: Seems to work for `stop` but not for disable :c Says `Failed to disable unit: Unit file uds_@\x2a.service does not exist.`

Answer (score 4):

Looks like the asterisk must be shell escaped

```
# systemctl stop sshd@\*.service
```